# Dictionary of recursive tree nodes

Tags: vb.net, recursion, dictionary, treeview

I am batch printing through many assemblies of AutoCAD documents. I have a recursive method that goes through each drawing to verify if it has any children, and then goes into each children to see if *they* have any children... and so on (recursively).

It has occured that I encounter a drawing that I has already printed, and it is completely useless for me to go through that  drawing and print all it's children *again*.

So... I wanted to build a virtual list, if you will, of the exact replica of items in my tree view. I would use it to verify if the item I'm trying to print, already exists in the virtual list, if so ... then I would just insert the KeyValue in the tree, saving a lot of time.

I figured my declaration of my dictionary would look something like this ...

```
Dim dic_AllAssemblies As New Dictionary(Of String, TreeNodeCollection)
```

I took a screenshot for an example of my treeview:

[image: Recursive treeview]

The dictionary would contain the main top item "ADF020-080A0" as it's first key, and in that key the values of all it's children would be included ... Is that even possible? It might go down 6-7 levels or even more... Can a dictionary or ... list handle that? Or is there another method that I'm not yet aware of?

```
 ADF020-080A0
     ADF020-081A0
         M17981
         M17981
     ADF000-092AS
         Etc...
             Etc...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know any reason that would not work. With a Dictionary you have the `.ContainsKey(string)` to check for a duplicate key name. If the key is found, skip it.